# Create database before restore multiple files

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, backup, restore

I've several database, most of them have multiple files (both data and logs) and multiple diff and trn backups. I've already a restore script (scheduled and working on other server) that takes all the needed files and restores them through UNC path. There is a check at the beginning that verifies that the db exists, if not, throws an error. But I want instead to create the database and then restore it. I don't want to use the `MOVE` option on the `RESTORE` statement. I've made [some](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14849/move-restore-sql-server-2005-database-which-does-not-exist-before) [searches](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14849/move-restore-sql-server-2005-database-which-does-not-exist-before) and what I've found doesn't cover my needs.

So, how can I create a `CREATE` statement to match what I will restore on the next step? Maybe a silly question, but can't find how to do it.

**Edit**

From Aaron comment I get now why I can't prevent using `MOVE`. But then I should create the database with all the requiered filegroups, correct? Something [like this](http://sqlserverdb.blogspot.com.es/2012/09/creating-database-with-multiple-file_18.html):

```
CREATE DATABASE [Testdb] ON  PRIMARY 
    ( NAME = N'Testdb', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDBs\Testdb.mdf' , SIZE = 102400KB ,
      MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1048576KB ), 
 FILEGROUP [TEST_DATA] 
    ( NAME = N'Test_Data', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDBs\Test_Data.ndf' , SIZE = 5242880KB ,
      MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1048576KB ), 
 FILEGROUP [TEST_DATA2] 
    ( NAME = N'Test_Data2', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDBs\Test_Data2.ndf' , SIZE = 5242880KB ,
      MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1048576KB ), 
 FILEGROUP [TEST_INDEX] 
    ( NAME = N'Test_Index', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDBs\Test_Index.ndf' , SIZE = 5242880KB,
      MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1048576KB )
 LOG ON 
    ( NAME = N'Testdb_log', FILENAME = N'G:\SQLLogs\Testdb_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1048576KB,
      MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 1048576KB )
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Testdb] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is that you think that creating the database first will allow you to bypass `WITH MOVE`. This is not the case.

If the destination file paths don't match those contained in the backup file, the presence of a database (and its file locations) aren't going to make a difference. `RESTORE` is going to look at the file locations specified in the backup file, completely ignoring the existing database. And this can only be overridden by using `WITH MOVE`.

Comment: Hmmm...I get it now why I see so many references to using `MOVE`. Then when I create the database I should also create all the required data files and then use the `MOVE` to specify that location? I'm editing my question to add a basic script of the db creation, just to use it as a sample.

Comment: @Yaroslav I still don't know why you think you need to create an empty database first - what do you think that does to help the process? Just run your `RESTORE ... WITH MOVE` (and `WITH REPLACE` in case the database already exists).

Comment: Edited my question as you where answering. The main issue here is that we already have an script (scheduled and working) with all the restore process that I don't want to modify (at least until I feel confident I can do it without breaking anything) and just want to add a `create database` statement in case the database being restored doesn't exist. So I don't modify the rest of the already working script.

Comment: @Yaroslav I'm still confused about what is going to break. If your script that is scheduled and working is just running a `RESTORE` (with the change to add `WITH MOVE` of course), why do you think it will break if you don't create the destination database first? **`RESTORE` does not need the database to already exist.**